# How to use phpmailer send() function on centos 7

Tags: php, composer-php, phpmailer

I'm trying to install and create a server to send password recovery emails. I use PHPMailer for my recovery site, and it has the following structure:

```php
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

if (isset($_POST['userEmailReset']) && isset($_POST['email'])) {

    $usernameOfEmail = $_POST['userEmailReset'];
    $target_email = $_POST['email'];
    $password_generate = generateString($count);

    $password_sending_viaEmail = "SELECT count(*) FROM account WHERE name=:usernameOfEmail AND email=:target_email";
    $stmt_mail_sending = $sqlWeb->prepare($password_sending_viaEmail);
    $stmt_mail_sending->bindValue(':usernameOfEmail', $usernameOfEmail);
    $stmt_mail_sending->bindValue(':target_email', $target_email);
    $stmt_mail_sending->execute();
    $mail_sending_data_checking = $stmt_mail_sending->fetchColumn();
    $stmt_mail_sending->closeCursor();

    //print_r($mail_sending_data_checking);


    if ($usernameOfEmail == "") {
        echo 'emptyUserEmail';
    } else if (!preg_match("/^[0-9a-zA-Z-' ]*$/", $usernameOfEmail)) {
        echo 'invalidUserEmail';
    } else if (strlen($usernameOfEmail) <= 6 || strlen($usernameOfEmail) >= 50) {
        echo 'userEmailTooShort';
    } else if ($target_email == "") {
        echo 'emptyTargetEmail';
    } else if (!filter_var($target_email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        echo 'invalidTargetEmail';
    } else if (strlen($target_email) <= 6 || strlen($target_email) >= 50) {
        echo 'targetEmailTooShort';
    } else {
        if ($mail_sending_data_checking > 0) {

            $select_account = "SELECT * FROM account WHERE name=:userSelected";
            $stmt_acc_select = $sqlWeb->prepare($select_account);
            $stmt_acc_select->bindValue(':userSelected', $usernameOfEmail);
            $stmt_acc_select->execute();
            $fullname_selected = $stmt_acc_select->fetchAll();
            $stmt_acc_select->closeCursor();
            foreach ($fullname_selected as $fullname): endforeach;



            $email_to = $target_email;
            $output = "<div style='width: 90%; height: auto;border :1px solid #99b3e6;line-height: 5px;padding: 3px 0px;'>"
                    . "<h2 style='text-align: center;color: #ff751a;'>Password Recovery System - Thien Long Blood Tu 3D</h2>"
                    . "<h3 style='margin-left: 120px;color: black;'>Hello: <span style='color: #5c85d6;'>" . $fullname['full_name'] . "</span></h3>"
                    . "<h4 style='margin-left: 40px;color: black;'>Thien Long Blood Tu has received a request to recover the password for the account: <span style='color: #5c85d6;'>" . $usernameOfEmail . "</span></h4>"
                    . "<p style='margin-left: 80px;font-size: 16px;font-weight: 600;color: black;'>Temporary password for your account: <span style='color: red;' >" . $password_generate . "</span></p>"
                    . "<p style='margin-left: 80px;color: black;'>Please follow the steps below to update the password:</p>"
                    . "<p style='margin-left: 110px;color: black;'>Step 1: login account with temporary password <a href='#'>Here</a> .</p>"
                    . "<p style='margin-left: 110px;color: black;'>Step 2: select the change password tab to update the new password.</p>"
                    . "<div style='width: 100%; height: auto;background-color: black;color: white;padding: 1px 0px;line-height: 15px;font-weight: 600;'>"
                    . "<p style='margin-left: 40px;'>Thien Long Blood Tu 3D system sincerely informs friends to keep your account information safe, if there is any"
                    . "If you have any problems with logging in or setting up your account information, please contact us directly at Fanpage: <a style='color: red;'href='#'>Thien Long Blood Tu 3D</a>."
                    . "BQT Bloody Tu's Pen!</p>"
                    . "</div>"
                    . "</div>";



            $body = $output;
            $subject = "Password Recovery";

            include "../vendor/autoload.php";

            $mail = new PHPMailer;
            $mail->isSMTP(true);
            $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
            $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
            $mail->Username = "my_email@gmail.com";
            $mail->Password = "my_password";
            $mail->Port = 587;
            $mail->IsHTML(true);
            $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
            $mail->From = "my_email@gmail.com";
            $mail->FromName = "No Reply";
            $mail->Subject = $subject;
            $mail->Body = $body;
            $mail->AddAddress($email_to);

            if (!$mail->send()) {
                echo 'send_mail_failed';
            } else {
                $update_password_byEmail = "UPDATE account SET password=:gen_password WHERE name=:currentUser AND email=:currentEmail;";
                $stmt_gen_pass_update = $sqlWeb->prepare($update_password_byEmail);
                $stmt_gen_pass_update->bindValue(':gen_password', md5($password_generate));
                $stmt_gen_pass_update->bindValue(':currentUser', $usernameOfEmail);
                $stmt_gen_pass_update->bindValue(':currentEmail', $target_email);
                $stmt_gen_pass_update->execute();
                $stmt_gen_pass_update->closeCursor();

                echo 'send_mail_successful';
            }
        } else {
            echo 'send_mail_error';
        }
    }
}
```

I could use the send() function when working with xampp on localhost, but when I brought it up to centos 7, the send() function stopped working, and it always stepped to echo 'send_mail_failed';
I know that I didn't have phpmailer installed on the centos server, but I've looked everything up on the net, and the results only return installing and using the mail() function, postfix, and sendmail*, and the configuration did not completely done all the configure files that I need . I hope you can help me send emails from my website to clients using phpmailer on centos. Thank you very much.

Comment: Please make sure that the path `include "../vendor/autoload.php";` is correct. It is because if you just upload the vendor folder to your web folder as a subfolder, the path to be included should be `include "./vendor/autoload.php";`

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? And how is this problem related to Composer itself?

Comment: Also, if you haven't installed PHPMailer yet on your production system, how should that code work?

Comment: So the problem in this case was the mail did not send to the clients when they tried to recover thier pass work. I did try that on the localhost, and It worked fine, but when I uploaded my code into centos server, It did not send mail any more. I did try install phpmailer in centos server , still did not work at all.

Comment: Then please share more details, like an error message or your attempts to resolve the problem. If there is no error message shown, you need to enable error reporting